# Why no trace operator in $L^2(\Omega)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, sobolev-spaces

We have trace operator which allows us to define boundary values of an $H^1$ function. This is because of the fact that $C^\infty$ is dense in $H^1$ under the $H^1$ norm, I believe.

I'm sure either $C^0$ or $C^\infty$ is also dense in $L^2$ in the $L^2$ norm, so why no trace operator in this case? Or am I wrong?

Comment: It is worth to note that there exist a continuous linear operator $T:L^2(\Omega)\to W^{1-1/2,2}(\partial\Omega)^\ast$ if $\Omega$ has some regularity.

Comment: Hi @Tomás, can you give a reference for that?

Comment: Yes @tomglabst. Take a look in Lions-Magenes books: Non-Homogeneous Boundary Value Problems and Applications. For now, I do not remember the volume.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that even though you can of course define a trace $T: C^\infty(\overline \Omega) \to L^2(\partial \Omega)$, to be able to extend $T$ to all of $L^p(\Omega)$ in a meaningful way, it is not sufficient to have *any* old operator $T$, but you really want $T$ to be *continuous*, i.e. there would need to be a constant $C >0$ such that

$$\Vert Tf \Vert_{L^2(\partial \Omega)}\le C \Vert f \Vert_{L^2(\Omega)}$$

In this case we would be able extend $T$ to an operator $T: L^2( \Omega) \to L^2(\partial \Omega)$ nicely. This is the case if you take the $H^1$ norm instead of the $L^2$ norm. However, it's a good exercise to show that such a $C$ does not exist for $L^2$ (or indeed for any $L^p$ space). Consider something simple like $\overline \Omega = [0,1]$.

Comment: Can you give a hint how to do your suggested exercise please?

Comment: @soup: Sure. Consider a sequence $f_n$ of smooth functions that satisfy $f_n(1) = 1$ and such that the sequence goes to zero elsewhere (notice that for any such sequence, the first derivative will explode; this is essentially why $H^1$ gives us enough control over our functions to define a trace). But maybe the one-dimensional example is not optimal, as integrating over the boundary is the same as evaluating pointwise there. You can try the same idea on $\Omega = \mathbb R \times [0, \infty)$, though. Now integration over $\partial \Omega =  \mathbb R\times \{0\}$ makes a bit more sense. =)

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider the following  sequence of **continuous functions:**

$$f_j(x)=\frac{1}{1+\color{red}jdist(x,\partial\Omega)},~~~~~~x\in \Omega.$$

We have, $$0\le f_j(x)\le 1,~~~~~and ~~~~~f_j(x)=1,~~~x\in \partial\Omega.$$ furthermore, for every $x \in\Omega  $,  we have 
$f_j(x)\to 0$ thus, by convergences dominated theorem we get 
$$\Vert f_j \Vert^p_{L^p(\Omega)}\to0 $$

> Assume that $\Omega$ is bounded of class $C^1$ and there is a trace operator from $L^p(\Omega)~~$ to $~~L^p(\partial \Omega)$ then there exists a constant $C>0$ Such that for all $f \in L^p(\Omega)$ we have:
>   $$\Vert Tf \Vert_{L^p(\partial \Omega)}\le C \Vert f \Vert_{L^p(\Omega)}.$$

In particular, for every $j$ we have 
$$Area(∂\Omega)=\Vert Tf_j \Vert^p_{L^p(\partial \Omega)}\le C^p \Vert f_j \Vert^p_{L^p(\Omega)}\to0. $$
$$Area(∂\Omega)=0$$

which is absurd since $\Omega$ is a bounded of class $C^1$.