# How is $L^p(\partial \Omega)$ defined if $\Omega$ is an interval?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations

If $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ ($n\geq 1$), then $L^p(\Omega)$ is generally (in the context of PDEs) defined with respect the Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

For $n>1$, we can see $\partial \Omega$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ and thus define $L^p(\partial\Omega)$ with respect the Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$.

For an interval $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^{1}$, the boundary $\partial\Omega$ will be a set with two points, say $\{a,b\}$. What is $L^p(\{a,b\})$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\Omega = (a,b)$ is an interval, in most cases the "right" way to interpret $\partial \Omega$ is as the two-point set $\{a,b\}$, equipped with counting measure.  So $L^p(\partial \Omega)$ is the two-dimensional vector space of functions $f : \{a,b\} \to \mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$) with the norm $\|f\|_{L^p(\partial \Omega)} = (|f(a)|^p + |f(b)|^p)^{1/p}$.

Of course, in any given context, it is worth checking to see if this interpretation makes sense, or if something else is intended.

Answer (score 1):

The bug is when you say that you can see $\partial \Omega $ as a subset of $\mathbb R^{n-1}$. Your example show exactly that.

And in all generality, I don't know if you can give to $\partial \Omega$ a "natural measure".

Comment: I think that there is some common definition or convention, but I couldn't find it. [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/332617) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/239526)  $L^p(\partial\Omega)$ is considered with $\Omega$ being an interval. In the [comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239521/why-no-trace-operator-in-l2#comment530864_239526) was said that, in this case, "integrating over the boundary is the same as evaluating pointwise there". Do you understand what is the measure that is being considered there?

Comment: In a general case, you could try to puy on $\partial \omega$ a structure of sub variety of $R^n$ of dimension $n-1$. Then, it is possible to use the differential structure to build a theory of the integration larger than the one of Lebesgue, to give a general meaning to $\int_{\partial \Omega}$